# create vertically non-overlapping labels next to boxplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap, boxplot, direct-labels

If want to create a boxplot with overlaid points which are labeled at the right hand side. I tried `geom_dl` form the `directlabels` package, but get stuck.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

set.seed(0)
x <- data.frame(label=LETTERS[1:15], 
                x="a",
                y = rnorm(15))
x$xpos <- as.numeric(x$x) + .25

g <- ggplot(x, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=.4) +
  geom_point(col="blue")
```

Position labels without overlap control using method [`last.points`.](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/lineplot/posfuns/last.points.html)

```
g + geom_dl(aes(x=xpos, label=label), method = "last.points")
```

[image]

Using method [`last.qp`](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/lineplot/posfuns/last.qp.html) to avoid overlaps fails.

```
g + geom_dl(aes(x=xpos, label=label), method = "last.qp")   # fails

Error in approx(df[, x.var], df[, tiebreak.var], xvals) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

**Any ideas, how to get `geom_dl` running or achieve proper placemant in another way?**

**Add-on**

Using method `last.bumpup` as @lukeA suggested below works quite fine. However, some labels are still overlapping. Is there a way to tweak this?

[image]

**Add-on 2**

I think the problem only arises when using a factor with more than one level on `x`.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- data.frame(label=LETTERS[1:24], 
                g1 = c("a"),
                g2 = c("a", "b"),
                y = rnorm(24))
x$g1 <- as.factor(x$g1)
x$g2 <- as.factor(x$g2)
x$xpos1 <- as.numeric(x$g1) + .25
x$xpos2 <- as.numeric(x$g2) + .25
```

The label placement for the first plot is fine. For the second with two levels the overlaps remain.

```
# one group
ggplot(x, aes(x=g1, y=y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=.4) +
  geom_point(col="blue") +
  geom_dl(aes(x=xpos1, label=label), method= "last.bumpup")
```

[image]

Two levels

```
# two groups
ggplot(x, aes(x=g2, y=y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=.4) +
  geom_point(col="blue") +
  geom_dl(aes(x=xpos2, label=label), method= "last.bumpup")
```

[image]

Comment: I use `directlabels_2015.12.16` and `ggplot2_2.1.0`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! My version of directlabels was way out of date

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`last.bumpup`](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/lineplot/posfuns/last.bumpup.html) method, which combines `last.points` and `bumpup` (`last.bumup <- list("last.points","bumpup")`):

```
g + geom_dl(aes(x=xpos, label=label), method = "last.bumpup")
```

[image]

Comment: nice, thanks! However, I still get overlap (see add-on above). Any ideas for this?

Comment: Strange, there should not be any overlaps. Maybe reduce font size and/or increase the y limits or the device height: `g + geom_dl(aes(x=xpos, label=label), method = list("last.bumpup", cex=.8)) + ylim(c(min(x$y), max(x$y)*10))` or `ggsave(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"), g + geom_dl(aes(x=xpos, label=label), method = "last.bumpup") + ylim(c(min(x$y), max(x$y)*15)), dpi = 320, height=12); shell.exec(tf)`

Comment: Thanks for the code. I figured that the problem only arises when using multiple levels on x (see add-on 2 above). A bug?

Comment: I don't know. If everything fails, I'd use facets like `+ facet_wrap(~g2, scales = "free_x") +  theme(panel.margin=unit(0, "cm"))`.